# Rate limiting specific IP adresses on Cisco 2960S and 2960X series

Tags: cisco, qos, bandwidth, cisco-2960

We are looking into rate limiting some specific IP addresses down to 5mbit for various bandwidth reasons.

Is is possible to rate limit ingress and egress traffic for specific IP addressees on the 2960S and 2960X series?

We know we can use "srr-queue bandwidth limit 50" combined with "speed 10" to limit egress traffic on a interface to 5mbit, but this will then apply to all IP's and not just the specific ones we want to limit.

If it is not possible, any chance it would be possible if we changed the SDM template to "lanbase-routing" as that enables some layer3 functionality?

Comment: You really don't want to do this on your 2960's...

Comment: Did any answer help you? if so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could post and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 3):

Try something like this:

```
mls qos

ip access-list extended ACL_SLAP
 permit ip any any


class-map match-all CLASS_SLAP
  match access-group name ACL_SLAP


policy-map POLICY_SLAP
  class CLASS_SLAP
    police 8000000 100000 exceed-action drop


interface GigabitEthernet0/2
 service-policy input POLICY_SLAP
```

Comment: Well that works, but in the wrong direction...

We ended up using almost this exact config at a different point in our network on a 4500-X switch since that supported "service-policy output"